# Go directly to a method from Connections Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Is there a way to go directly to an action or outlet from the Connections Inspector within XCode?

In the example below to go directly to the method "addDocuments" or outlet "plusButton"

[image: Connections Inspector]

I usually root around in the Assistant Editor to until I find it, but is there a quicker way?

Comment: use command+shift+O, the Fuzzy Match Search to locate quickly

Comment: Please be clear.. What do u mean by directly go to..?

Comment: For XCode to take me to the method definition, a little like the reverse of this: http://imgur.com/L6BsTYP

Answer (score 3):

**No**, There is not direct way to jump from connection inspector to object or IBAction.

Comment: Frustrating, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah :) May be some one can write a plugin for this!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to view this is to do a Command-shift-O or File -> Open Quickly.